# IIS 10 Service upload on Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, upload, windows-server, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a WebApp that uploads files to a server, but it is not working in a Google VM with Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10 to files larger than 1MB. It works on others servers with IIS8.5 and WS 2012. When I try to upload, it takes a lot of time, returns a success message, but the file does not go to the folder on the server.

That problem does not occours when I access my webapp from the server itself or another Google VM. It looks like a firewall problem, but I do not found anything different there.

There is some different configuration on WS 2016 or IIS 10 that explains Why it is happening?

Comment: Since it is working in the VM and also from another google VM,it looks like issue is outside your application or IIS.IIS does not allow to upload the file if it is about the configured size no matter how you access it. Since it is wokring locally and also from other VMS, You should check with google support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a VPN that had been disabled, but still blocking the connections. I just remove the VPN and all start to work.